PT100 smart sensor design - protection PT100 input against 24V DC
I'm trying to design a smart PT100 sensor and I would like to protect the 3-wire PT100 input against accidentally applying 24V DC. Is my solution work correct and protect the op amp, ref3030 and the rest of the components? I'm a beginner in electronics, and I make some mistakes.


NO. Because it would fry the TVS diodes. The AD623 itself has protection diodes, max 10mA current. You have to calculate R25 & R27 so that at 24V the current will be bellow 10mA. For REF you have to do the same or add some buffer.
